# Выучил основы java, дошел до сериализации, сокетов,многопоточности но все равно не в силах написать свой хотя бы простенький проект.

Tags: java

Знаю что этих знаний мало, но может кто подскажет как вообще начать что либо писать если не знаешь сам, а в интернете мало видосов с кодингом или попадается какая то фигня. Например если есть идея програмки или типа того но не знаешь как это реализовать ?!

Comment: "Угадал все буквы, не смог назвать слово" (с). | _мало видосов_ - может дело в этом? Отказаться от видосов и перейти к книгам? | _есть идея программки_ - начинайте реализовывать программу; что-то **конкретное** не получается - спрашивайте.

Comment: Не подкрепляя, свои знания практикой ни от книг ни от видосиков толку не будет.

Comment: Нужно искать доступную по силам практику, брать идею, продумывать реализацию и пробовать. Если что то не идет (например GUI) - делать как получается или заглушку, и разбираться, не бросая основной функционал. Вот хороший пример пошаговой реализации небольшой программы https://annimon.com/article/308. Автор берет идею, изучает нужную, но новую для него технологию, тестирует, применяет.

Answer (score 1):

1. Перейдите с коротких и малоинформативных видео на [лекции](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XC8RmEn5gYA&list=PLlb7e2G7aSpQith1Z6xRpU8jFPgkh_Gvz), или книги. Они будут на более информатированными.
2. Смотри на код опытных программистов и от туда ты будешь уносить их стиль писания кода, хорошие привычки и архитектуру.
3. Разговаривай с программистами из разных отраслей и у тебя будет широкий кругозор, что обязательно поможет.
4. Практикуйся.

**К созданию программ** Когда у тебя возникает идея для программы тебе сначала следует обдумать программу. Представь архитектуру программы. Ты должен понять в силах ли реализовать её.

Если да начинай создание. В обратном случае иди и выучи, что тебе надо и возвращайся к архитектуре.

Далее берешь и пишешь программу. Тестируеш, оптимизируешь и наблюдаешь результат.

**P.S.** на мой взгляд твоих знаний чересчур мало. Лучше выучи Java SE и освой Maven, JUnit и не сколько библиотек дополнительно. Тебе будет легче писать с большим чемоданом знаний.